Cypress: Mocking Image URLs in Responses for <img> Elements
Background
I am testing a system consisting of a (React) frontend and a backend server. I am trying to write a Cypress test suite for my frontend to validate its presentation logic.
In these tests, I am mocking out my backend calls using sample JSON for each response and making use of Cypress's interceptor feature to catch backend calls and replace them with my mock.
The Problem
A few of my API endpoints return URLs to images (S3 signed URLs), which the frontend displays in  HTML elements. Since the actual URLs point to images not directly served by my frontend, I want to mock these image URLs in my Cypress tests so the images actually display in Cypress's simulation.
I am struggling to find a way to do this.
What I've tried
Attempt 1
I used cy.loadImageFixture to generate base64 data URLs from fixture files and manually added them into the mocked JSON responses:
cy.loadImageFixture('avatar1.svg').then((imageUrl) => {
      const mockedResponse: LoginResponse = {
        userId: 1,
        username: 'testUser',
        avatar: {
          name: 'avatars/default/avatar1.svg',
          url: imageUrl
        }
      }
    })

In this example, adding the URL is trivial. But some of my mocked responses contain many different URLs, and this approach is not scalable (pyramid of doom). Also, I would ideally like to keep the mock data and the Cypress logic separate.
Attempt 2
Instead of manually adding base64 URLs to the response, I updated my mock JSON to include dummy image URLs and planned to intercept these during tests to serve data URLs for the fixtures:
const mockLoginResponse: LoginResponse = {
  userId: 1,
  username: 'adam',
  avatar: {
    name: './avatars/default/avatar3.svg',
    url: './avatars/default/avatar3.svg'
  }
}

cy.intercept('POST', '/api/login', {
  statusCode: HttpStatusCode.Ok,
  body: mockLoginResponse
})

Then, I used this helper to intercept the fake img src URLs and redirect to the fixture image files:
Cypress.Commands.add('setupAvatarUrlInterceptors', () => {
  const avatarFiles = [
    'avatar1.svg',
    'avatar2.svg',
    'avatar3.svg'
    // and many more
  ]

  avatarFiles.forEach((avatarFile) => {
    cy.fixture(`./images/${avatarFile}`, 'base64').then((base64Image) => {
      const dataUrl = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64Image}`

      cy.intercept(`./avatars/default/${avatarFile}`, (req) => {
        req.redirect(dataUrl, HttpStatusCode.Ok)
      })
    })
  })
})

I like this approach a lot more. The intercept logic triggers correctly, and I see the redirects in the Cypress console, but the images do not render in the  elements on the page. The browser continues to reference the original (dummy) URLs. I think there would need to be another step in finding all src attributes and replacing them. This is a headache because I would have to make a call to this replacer every time I make a network call that involves these images, which would clutter my tests.
What I’m Looking For
I’d like the mocked responses to remain JSON/TS fixture files (Cypress-independent), and dynamically map their dummy image URLs to actual images during runtime. Is there a better way to handle this in Cypress so the images render in <img> elements?
Note
I do not want to include these images in my public folder

Intercept the general pattern for the avatars, find out which specific avatar from the URL then apply the fixture dynamically.
Since you control the mocks in /images you don't need base64.
cy.intercept('**/avatars/default/*', (req) => {
  const img = req.url.split('/').at(-1)
  req.reply({
    fixture: `../../images/${img}`
  })
})



I should have made this more clear in the post -- My requests are more complicated than just getting a single image at a time. They include other data. The login request I shared is not just the image.
My second approach was trying to intercept the img src url. And unfortunately it does not work.
From my understanding, I cannot follow a simple fixture pattern like this.
